# RabbitMQ Storing SSL Certificate in windows certificate store

Tags: ssl, rabbitmq

Is it possible to store the client certificate for rabbitmq *server* in the windows certificate store? 
I know that doing so in the c# client is supported, but haven't seen any mention of a similar option for the server itself. 
the ssl_options in rabbit.config mention only using certificates stored on the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time. Support for the Windows cert store would have to be added to Erlang itself.

Comment: I assume support for the Windows Cert store still not yet available (I am using OTP 21.1)

Comment: You can verify that by reading the Erlang/OTP documentation and/or release notes.